# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after upgrading to Xcode6 Beta3 Setting Navigation Title

Tags: xcode, swift, exc-bad-access, navigationitem

(Xcode6 beta3, Swift, iOS8, iPhone)

Just upgraded from Xcode6 to beta3. Code that was working fine is now breaking.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.title = "Principles" // ERROR THROWN HERE

}
```

Error Reads:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffc)
```

Also, it works on the simulator, but *not* on the device (a 4S that I use for testing)

Comment: Did you update the iPhone to the latest beta as well?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Do a Clean and then rerun it. For some, making a copy of the whole project seems to solve the bad access bug

Comment: In my case the app was a relatively small prototype with just seven views, so I just manually reconstructed it. I created a new project, re-created the classes, copy n' pasted the code from the old project, and re-wired everything. Perhaps a good option for those with small projects, those exasperated with the bug, or those who want a squeaky-clean build for deployment.

Comment: It was actually a pretty good experience, and didn't take that long. I was also able to tidy up some code and get rid of some garbage that didn't need to be there... perhaps contributors to this bug.